# Calculation of DFFITS as diagnostic for Leverage and Influence in regression

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I am trying to calculate DFFITS by hand. The value obtained should be equal to the first value obtained by `dffits` function. However there must be something wrong with my own calculation.

```
attach(cars)

x1 <- lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars) # all observations

x2 <-  lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars[-1,]) # without first obs

x <- model.matrix(speed ~ dist) # x matrix

h <- diag(x%*%solve(crossprod(x))%*%t(x)) # hat values

num_dffits <- x1$fitted.values[1] - x2$fitted.values[1] #Numerator

denom_dffits <- sqrt(anova(x2)$`Mean Sq`[2]*h[1]) #Denominator

df_fits <- num_dffits/denom_dffits #DFFITS

dffits(x1)[1] # DFFITS function
```

Comment: In the  numerator , it is the difference between the first fitted value with all observations and the first fitted values with out the first observation. In the denominator, it is the square root of variance of fitted value with out the first observation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your numerator is wrong. As you have removed first datum from the second model, corresponding predicted value is not in `fitted(x2)`. We need to use `predict(x2, cars[1, ])` in place of `fitted(x2)[1]`.

---

Hat values can be efficiently computed by

```
h <- rowSums(qr.Q(x1$qr) ^ 2)
```

or using its R wrapper function

```
h <- hat(x1$qr, FALSE)
```

R also has a generic function for getting hat values, too:

```
h <- lm.influence(x1, FALSE)$hat
```

or its wrapper function

```
h <- hatvalues(x1)
```

---

You also don't have to call `anova` to get MSE:

```
c(crossprod(x2$residuals)) / x2$df.residual
```