# DFFITs for Beta Regression

Tags: r, outliers

I am trying to calculate DFFITS for GLM, where responses follow a Beta distribution. By using `betareg` R package. But I think this package  doesn't support `influence.measures()` because by using `dffits()`
**Code**

```
require(betareg)
df<-data("ReadingSkills")
y<-ReadingSkills$accuracy
n<-length(y)

bfit<-betareg(accuracy ~ dyslexia + iq, data = ReadingSkills)
DFFITS<-dffits(bfit, infl=influence(bfit, do.coef = FALSE))
DFFITS
```

it yield

> Error in if (model$rank == 0) { : argument is of length zero

I am a newbie in R. I don't know how to resolve this problem. Kindly help to solve this or give me some tips through R code that how to calculate DFFITs manually.
Regards

Comment: See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Provide your data and code you have tried so far.

Comment: @BappaDas I could reproduce it without the `infl=` argument.

Comment: @jay.sf After the comment, the OP has updated the post. When I have commented, the dataset and code were not available.

Comment: @BappaDas Ah, I see now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dffits` are not implemented for `"betareg"` objects, but you could try to calculate them manually.

According to [this Stack Overflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44778302/6574038) we could write this function:

```
dffits1 <- function(x1, bres.type="response") {
  stopifnot(class(x1) %in% c("lm", "betareg"))
  sapply(1:length(x1$fitted.values), function(i) {
    x2 <- update(x1, data=x1$model[-i, ]) # leave one out
    h <- hatvalues(x1)
    nm <- rownames(x1$model[i, ])
    num_dffits <- suppressWarnings(predict(x1, x1$model[i, ]) - 
                                     predict(x2, x1$model[i, ]))
    residx <- if (class(x1) == "betareg") {
      betareg:::residuals.betareg(x2, type=bres.type)
    } else {
      x2$residuals
    }
    denom_dffits <- sqrt(c(crossprod(residx)) / x2$df.residual*h[i])
    return(num_dffits / denom_dffits)
  })
}
```

It works well for `lm`:

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)
dffits1(fit)
stopifnot(all.equal(dffits1(fit), dffits(fit)))
```

Now let's try `betareg`:

```
library(betareg)
data("ReadingSkills")

bfit <- betareg(accuracy ~ dyslexia + iq, data=ReadingSkills)
dffits1(bfit)
#           1           2           3           4           5           6           7 
# -0.07590185 -0.21862047 -0.03620530  0.07349169 -0.11344968 -0.39255172 -0.25739032 
#           8           9          10          11          12          13          14 
#  0.33722706  0.16606198  0.10427684  0.11949807  0.09932991  0.11545263  0.09889406 
#          15          16          17          18          19          20          21 
#  0.21732090  0.11545263 -0.34296030  0.09850239 -0.36810187  0.09824013  0.01513643 
#          22          23          24          25          26          27          28 
#  0.18635669 -0.31192106 -0.39038732  0.09862045 -0.10859676  0.04362528 -0.28811277 
#          29          30          31          32          33          34          35 
#  0.07951977  0.02734462 -0.08419156 -0.38471945 -0.43879762  0.28583882 -0.12650591 
#          36          37          38          39          40          41          42 
# -0.12072976 -0.01701615  0.38653773 -0.06440176  0.15768684  0.05629040  0.12134228 
#          43          44 
#  0.13347935  0.19670715
```

Looks not bad.

**Notes:**

- Even if this works in code, you should check if it meets your statistical requirements!
- I've used `suppressWarnings` in lines `5:6` of `dffits1`.  `predict(bfit, ReadingSkills)` drops the `contrasts` somehow,  whereas `predict(bfit)` does not (should practically be the same). However the results are identical: `all.equal(predict(bfit, ReadingSkills), predict(bfit))`, thus ignoring the warnings be safe.

Comment: thanks a lot. Can you explain one more thing? In `denom_dffits` which type of residuals are used? Usually response residual are used, if I want to change its type thn at which step changes will be done?

Comment: @JAK I've changed the code, but I think it's superfluous because you referred to the residuals, do you think I should roll back my answer? `?lm` states `"the residuals, that is response minus fitted values."` and `?betareg` states `"residuals: a vector of raw residuals (observed - fitted)"`.

Comment: you provide the chance to change pridiction types, but I want variation in residuals. check this`?betareg:::residuals.betareg()`

Comment: very nice. JazakAllah God Bless you.